# How to label ('vertically') points in graph

Tags: matlab

I would like to add labels to some points plotted using the command `scatter`. For the sake of simplicity, let's say I have only one point:

```
x = 10;
pointSize = 100;
fontSize = 20;

P = scatter(x, 0, pointSize, [0,0,0], 'filled');

text(x, 0, 'pointLabel',... 
     'HorizontalAlignment', 'center',...
     'VerticalAlignment', 'bottom',... 
     'FontSize', fontSize);
```

The problem with the previous commands is that the text `pointLabel` overlaps with the point `P` depending on the values assigned to the properties `pointsize` and `fontSize`.

I have read the documentation of the `text` command, but the examples only show how to put a label horizontally aligned with a specific point in the diagram. If the alignment needs to be horizontal it is easy, but I could not find a general way to compute the `y` coordinate of the label `pointLabel` from the values of the other dimensions.

Clearly I can reach a good alignment by testing various combinations of values, but I am looking for a general solution.

Is there anyone who can help me?

Comment: Keep in mind that `text` accepts coordinates in the **axes** domain. This means that if you apply some constant offset (e.g. `2`), it might look good in some cases but horribly bad in others. You can either re-scale the offset based on the data limits, or consider the `annotation` function. The `annotation` function accepts **figure** coordinates, so there's a higher chance that a constant offset value of e.g `0.2` would look good regardless of the data limits. In the 2nd option, you will need to translate coordinates; see "Data space to figure units conversion" in FEX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This assumes you are using >=R2014b, though it can also be accomplished in older versions using `set` and `get` commands.

When a text object is created, its default units are data coordinates, but those can be changed. In your case, I'd go with points.

```
x = 10;
pointSize = 100;
fontSize = 20;

P = scatter(x, 0, pointSize, [0,0,0], 'filled');

t = text(x, 0, 'pointLabel',... 
     'HorizontalAlignment', 'center',...
     'VerticalAlignment', 'bottom',... 
     'FontSize', fontSize);

% It's always a good idea to switch back to the default units, so remember them.
originalUnits = t.Units; 
t.Units = 'points';

% Shift the text up by the sqrt(pi)/2 times the radius of the point
t.Position(2) = t.Position(2) + sqrt(pointSize)/2;
t.Units = originalUnits;
```

Check out [Text Properties](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/text-properties.html) for more info. If you want to get really sophisticated, you can use the read-only property `Extent` and your known marker size and position to calculate when a label is overlapping one of your points. Since the default unit is in data space, no conversions are necessary.

If you're working with an older version of MATLAB, all of these options and properties are still available, you just have to work a little harder to use them. For instance, you can't direction set the position as above, but you would instead use `get` to assign it to a temporary variable, change it, and then use `set` to update. More lines of code, but ultimately the same effect.

Comment: Thank you, but I do not understand why you lift up `t` by `fontsize/2` instead of `sqrt(pointSize)/2`. This is the code which produces nice results: 
`originalUnits = get(t, 'Units');
set(t, 'Units', 'points');
tPos = get(t, 'Position');
tPos(2) = tPos(2) + sqrt(pointSize)/2; 
set(t, 'Position', tPos);
set(t, 'Units', originalUnits);`

Comment: `sqrt(pointSize)` just as an example: it is the `pointSize` value which is annoying, not the `fontsize`. Anyway, thanks to your answer I managed to get a quite-general solution.

Comment: I used the amount to shift up as an example. The main point was that you can query the `position` and `units` of each text label and move it however you like in whatever units you like. You could also use the `Extent` properties to shift left and right to keep from bumping into other points.